# How to configure tfs build to copy dlls upon release build completion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying to configure TFS 2012 build definition. What I want is to create a release build of one of my solutions and once it is successfully built, copy dlls into some shared location in source control so it can be referenced by other solutions. I also dont want to create a separate folder for every minor build (e.g. 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.2 etc), only for major releases (1.0, 2.0, 3.0). So if I am running a build for version 1.0 it should just overwrite dlls in shared folder for v1.0. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. I have created a copy of the default build template, then I opened it in visual studio. I had to create a new Custom Argument and called it ReleaseLocation and added it to metadata so it is available in Build definition editor. I then navigated to "Copy Files to Drop Location" and added another "If" condition, which checks if ReleaseLocation is not null. In "Then " condition I dragged and dropped "CopyDirectory" task from toolbox and configured it to copy files from BinaryDirectory to ReleaseLocation. Now, I chose this newly created template for my build definition and added desired folder for ReleaseLocation.